# What is the distribution of time to absorption for an absorbing Markov chain?

Tags: probability, markov-chains, markov-process

I am interested in finding the distribution of time to absorption for a given absorbing Markov chain transition matrix. I've looked at first passage time (where $f_{ij}^{(n)}$ is the probability that the first passage from $i$ to $j$ occurs in exactly $n$ steps).

In my particular case I have a single absorbing state, which I'll call $j$. I think I can find the probability mass function since $P(x=0)=0\cdot f_{ij}^{(0)}, P(x=1)=1 \cdot f_{ij}^{(1)}, \ldots $, but I'm not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The distribution of a random variable representing time-to-absorption of a Markov chain with a single absorbing state is called a [discrete phase-type distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_phase-type_distribution).

Summarising the wiki article: assume the last row of the $n\times n$ transition matrix corresponds to the absorbing state and let $T$ be the upper left $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ block.  The pmf for the absorption time given initial distribution $\tau$ is then
$$p(k) = \tau T^{k-1} T_0 $$
where $T_0$ is the vector formed by the first $n-1$ entries of the last column of the transition matrix, showing that these distributions are generalisations of the geometric distribution.

Comment: is it possible to derive this formula?