# Expected hitting time of a certain state in a Markov chain

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

> Let's consider the following Markov chain. If we start at state $2$, compute the probability to hit $4$ and the expected time until it happens.
>
> [image]

The probability to hit $4$ in $n$ steps starting at $2$ is $Pr(X_n=4|X_0=2)=(\frac{1}{2})^n$ if $n$ is even, and $0$ if $n$ is odd. Then, the total probability of hitting 4 if we start at 2 will be$\sum_{n\geq1}Pr(X_n=4|X_0=2)=\sum_{i\geq1}(\frac{1}{2})^{2i}=\sum_{i\geq1}\frac{1}{4^i}=\frac{1}{3}$

How can I calculate $\mathbb{E}(T_{24})?$ I have tried considering the mean hitting times $m_{ij}$, so $m_{24}=1+\frac{1}{2}m_{14}+\frac{1}{2}m_{34}$ and $m_{34}=1+\frac{1}{2}m_{44}+\frac{1}{2}m_{24}=1+\frac{1}{2}m_{24}$.

The solution in my book is $m_{24}=m_{34}=3$, which does not seem intuitive to me.

Comment: Your intuition is good. To get to state 4 from state 2, the system must always go through 3, so it would be highly surprising for the mean absorption times to be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get $m_{24}=4$ and $m_{34}=3$.  We are computing the expected time to hit state $4$ starting in state $2$, assuming that it happens.  There is a positive probability that we never reach state $4$ so if we don't condition the expectation on success, it would be $\infty.$

Therefore, we have to adjust the state diagram.  The arrow from state $2$ to state $1$ goes away, and the arrow from state $2$ to state $3$ gets weight $1$.  Now we have
$$\begin{align}
m_{24}&=1+m_{34}\\
m_{34}&=1+\frac12 m_{24}
\end{align}$$
which leads to the solutions I gave above.  You may find the accepted answer to [Expected time till absorption in specific state of a Markov chain](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2852105/expected-time-till-absorption-in-specific-state-of-a-markov-chain) instructive.

Comment: $m_{24}=4$ and $m_{34}=3$ makes more sense than the results in the book (wrong by sure). Thanks for the answer and the useful link!

Comment: @Gibbs It was my pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

The general way for computing mean hitting times of *any* absorbing state is well known, rather easily proven and in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_Markov_chain#Expected_number_of_steps).

To get the mean hitting time of a *specific* state (or subset of states), we simply condition the outcome on hitting that state. For this question, the modified chain looks like:

[image]

This gives us the transition matrix $\Pi$, where $\Pi_{ij}$ gives the probability of transitioning to state *j* from state *i*:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0\\ 
\frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2}\\ 
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

And *Q*:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\ 
\frac{1}{2} & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

So that
$$
\begin{align}
m &= (I-Q)^{-1}1 \\
&= 
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 2 \\ 
1 & 2
\end{pmatrix}1 \\
&= 
\begin{pmatrix}
4 \\ 
3
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
$$

Indeed, $m_{24} = 4$ and $m_{34} = 3$.